# Hard drive is detected as USB flash drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, usb, usb-flash-drive

My external hard drive (USB 3.0) is detected as a USB flash drive in 'My Computer' and I can't access the device by using Window Explorer and from the command line. Before that happened, it installed its own driver called (NORELSYS 106X USB) automatically. I tried in another PC, but I still got the same result. Nothing was detected when I tried to connect the external hard drive in Linux (Ubuntu).

[image]

When I checked in Disk Management, it shows as the below screenshots:

[image]

Here is my Device Properties:

[image]

Is there any way to recover my hard drive or my data?

Comment: More information on the device itself is required.  If this is a flash device your more then likely out of luck.

Comment: It sounds like the hard drive is dead.

Comment: The good news is you could attempt to remove the hdd from the enclosure because the driver is a USB to SATA driver which means its not a flash drive.

Comment: I would hate to scare you too much, but if you got it from a less scrupulous the drive might be fake and just contain a USB stick that was hacked to report a larger size, or something like that. Then the case is filled with scrap metal to make it feel heavy. http://i.imgur.com/t5x6zpa.jpg To that end, can you hear or feel it spin up when you plug it in? If not, did it ever?

Comment: I pretty sure that was hard drive because I changed other external hard drive case from current one by myself. There is impossible for being fake flash drive as @nitro2k01 mentioned. On the top of that, It was 500GB hard drive and only 100 GB of space are free. I doubt that Is there any of 400 GB space with USB flash drive.